# CSS: White bar on the side of my product pages

Tags: html, css

My product pages have a white bar on the side of them that make them wider than my browser. I've checked on another computer and have the same thing. See: https://vaped.ca/products/healthy-rips-fury-edge-vaporizer - I've also attached a screenshot.

This is only happening on my product pages.. not on the homepage or collection, so it isn't site-wide.

I'm happy to donate to anyone who helps me solve this! Thank you )

[image: white bar css]

Answer (score 2):

It is your **.jdgm-review-widget**. Get rid of the padding and your good to go:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .jdgm-review-widget:not(.jdgm-review-widget--medium) .jdgm-histogram {
     margin: 16px 0 0 0;
     /* padding: 0 50% 0 34%; */
     border: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Checking how to fix that with the app developer! Thank you. Drop a donation link here if you'd like :)

Comment: Make a donation to charity if you'd like :) Thank you.